# Edit audio output before playback

Tags: linux, audio, devices, alsa

I want to low level edit the output of ALSA sound system. I should sniff the audio output, change it before playback and then play it. I saw `/dev/snd/OUTDEVICE` but I think it is write only. Which is the right way to to this?

Comment: See `snd-aloop`.